# Custom Filter on bootstrap-table.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I´m using the "bootstrap-table.js" to list/show my data.

I have some columns and the existing filter is great to search data in all columns, but I need to buid a custom filter to filter a specific column only.

I wanna use both, the existing filter and a custom filter either.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help...